# Keep navbar fixed to a specific position on bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following scenario:

[Current Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/hY4h6/)

On this fiddle I'm trying to set the `.navbar` positioned just below the big jumbotron to be a fixed navbar as soon as the user starts scrolling past the said navbar. I tried using bootstrap's `.navbar-fixed-top` but it sends it back to the top. `position: fixed` makes the navbar go God knows where.

That's all I could come up with whilst trying to make the navbar fixed to that specific position. Can this be done only with CSS? I'm starting to think maybe some jQuery may be required.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Bootstrap has the `affix` plugin.

Comment: Reading the documentation at the moment. Not sure how it works really. Can you be a little bit more clear?

Comment: So here's what's funny: you blew off the answer from @Jeff which requires no plugins, just straight up Bootstrap, and instead chose the answer that requires the plugin!  Here's a demo of the non-plugin version that Jeff recommended updated for Bootstrap 3: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/2t5WB/.  It's not that I'm trying to make you change your mind, it's just especially funny because of that website you shared in the comments to Jeff's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand
Use a jquery plugin called as **Sticky**

You can find it [here](http://stickyjs.com)

You can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stick").sticky({topSpacing:20});
  });
```

Just change the spacing if required.

I have also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TA8Xu/1/) for this.

Comment: Does the job. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has the [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) plugin. The documentation Table of Contents on the right side of the Bootstrap docs use this itself.

A quick google search got me this fiddle (I did not write this, credit to whoever did): http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/df8tb/

HTML:

```
 <div class="container" id="con">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="well">
                    <h1> Header </h1>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400" id="nav">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>
                         <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span3">
            <p style="height:1000px;padding:10px;">

                Long scrolling text here... Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo.  Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo. Ovi lispmd idr. Blah goo bar foor foo.

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#nav').affix({
});
```

Comment: @hsoto if you are including bootstrap as a whole you already have it.

Comment: @hsoto And I saw that site too, hillarious :P - really though, if thats your way of thinking, ditch bootstrap all-together. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jquery, but I believe this is what you are looking for: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy. I've done some Ruby On Rails with bootstrap, so this is where I'm coming from.

EDIT: No need for additional jQuery! Bootstrap is cool enough to do things like this.

Comment: That's for the scrolling of content, not the actual navbar.

Comment: Then the scrollspy is useless. Why can't you just make  a scrollable area and just put a navbar element above? Right? Or do I not know what I'm talking about? (Probably)

Comment: Probably you do not know what you're talking about. The page will be made with angular.js and will be a SPA, Single Page Application. I do not need scrollable areas.

Comment: @Tqn `No need for jQuery!`, well, Bootstrap is built on jQuery, so technically you do need it. ;)